# Query (Sort) field Firestore KOTLIN

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I try query(Sort) one of my fields in Firestore by input a value from a spinner, But I doesn't get it work. Should I use "whereEqualTo" or "orderBy"?

Here is my code:

```
        override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {

            firestoreDB.collection("posts")
                .whereEqualTo("genre", position)
                .get().addOnSuccessListener {
                    println(it.documents)
                }
            val type = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
            Toast.makeText(activity,type, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
```

Comment: Hello and welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read how to ask an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `orderBy`, because `whereEqualTo` returns only documents where `"genre"` equal to `position`.